# Name \pic object using loop variable

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, tikz-pic

What is the good way to name `\pic` object when `\foreach` variable is used? I use the variable in `\foreach` as part of the node name. If I do not using `local bounding box`, then there is no shape name error. If I use `local bounding box`, there is another error related to field name. Below is the code I use.

```
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        pics/multisquare/.style args={#1/#2}{
            code={%
                \node [draw, minimum height=.4em, minimum width=.8em,
                       fill=#1, inner sep=0pt] (s1) {};
                \node [draw, minimum height=.4em, minimum width=.8em,
                       fill=#2, anchor=north, inner sep=0pt] (s2) at (s1.south) {};}
        },
    ]
        \foreach \y in {0,...,4}
            \pic [local bounding box=node-\y] at (0, -\y) {multisquare=red/blue};

        \foreach \y in {0,...,4}
            \pic [local bounding box=node-\y] at (1.6, -\y) {multisquare=red/blue};

        % -----------------------------------------------------------
        % code below shows an error
        % \foreach \source in {0,...,4}
        %     \foreach \dest in {0,...,4}
        %         \draw [->] (node-\dest) -- (node-\source);
        % -----------------------------------------------------------

        % -----------------------------------------------------------
        % code below does not have an error
        \pic [local bounding box=node-1] at (0, 1) {multisquare=green/yellow};
        \pic [local bounding box=node-2] at (0, 2) {multisquare=green/yellow};

        \draw [->] (node-1) -- (node-2);
        % -----------------------------------------------------------

        % -----------------------------------------------------------
        % code below has an error
        % \pic (l3-1) at (0, 1) {multisquare=green/yellow};
        % \pic (l4-1) at (0, 2) {multisquare=green/yellow};

        % \draw [->] (l3-1) -- (l4-1);
        % -----------------------------------------------------------

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
```

To put it more precise, my plan is to define a new shape (or new node) that combines multiple shapes (or nodes). When using relative positioning, I want to use that new shape (or new node) as an object.

Comment: Unfortunately nobody can compile your code when copied. Please add the few missing lines. Thank you

Comment: I can compile the code using overleaf shown above without an error. And the answer provided by @Jasper can also be compiled without an error. I think you need `\usepackage{tikz}`?

Comment: What the comment means is that you cannot just copy the code and compile it. You need to add a `\documentclass` and `\usepackage{tikz}`. You should always include this in your code examples on this site, because often it is important to know which document class and packages are used to produce the output that is referred in the question.

Comment: @CNDominic, as Jasper said, try copying your posted code into a fresh file and compile. It doesn't matter, if you do it online with Overleaf or with a local installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you try to do, but I think where you got stuck is with how to reference a `\node` inside a `\pic`. Here is how you can do this: It is a convention to name nodes inside a `\pic` with a preceding `-` (hyphen-minus), for example `-s1`. Also, you can name a `\pic` just like a node, for example like this:

```
\pic (p1) at (0,1) {multisquare=green/yellow};
```

The name of this `\pic` is now `p1` and if there is a node in it named `-s1`, you can refer to this node with `p1-s1`. There is no need to use bounding boxes, and this would also work inside a `\foreach` loop.

Applied to your code, you could do something like the following:

```
\documentclass[border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        pics/multisquare/.style args={#1/#2}{
            code={
                \node[draw, minimum height=.4em, minimum width=.8em,
                    fill={#1}, inner sep=0pt] (-s1) {};
                \node[draw, minimum height=.4em, minimum width=.8em,
                    fill={#2}, anchor=north, inner sep=0pt] (-s2) at (-s1.south) {};
            }
        },
    ]

        \pic (p1) at (0,1) {multisquare={green/yellow}};
        \pic (p2) at (0,2) {multisquare={green/yellow}};

        \draw[->] (p1-s1) -- (p2-s2);


        \foreach \i in {3,4} {
            \pic (p\i) at (0,\i) {multisquare={red/blue}};
        }

        \draw[->] (p3-s1) -- (p4-s2);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You could also not use a node, but just a drawing in your `\pic` and set some coordinates:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        pics/multisquare/.style args={#1/#2}{
            code={
                \coordinate (-north) at (0,.4em);
                \coordinate (-south) at (0,-.4em);
                \draw[fill=#1] (-.4em,0em) rectangle (.4em,.4em);
                \draw[fill=#2] (-.4em,-.4em) rectangle (.4em,0em);
            }
        }
    ]

        \pic (p1) at (0,1) {multisquare={green/yellow}};
        \pic (p2) at (0,2) {multisquare={green/yellow}};

        \draw[->] (p1-north) -- (p2-south);


        \foreach \i in {3,4} {
            \pic (p\i) at (0,\i) {multisquare={red/blue}};
        }

        \draw[->] (p3-north) -- (p4-south);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want use a node but don't like to refer to different node names, you can use just one node and fill it with a `path picture`. You could probably also use a [multi-part node](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#pgf.rectangle:split), but I think adjusting the size is a bit more complicated then:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        multisquare/.style args={#1/#2}{
            draw, minimum height=.8em, minimum width=.8em, inner sep=0pt, 
            path picture={
                \fill[#1] (path picture bounding box.east) 
                    rectangle (path picture bounding box.north west);
                \fill[#2] (path picture bounding box.south east) 
                    rectangle (path picture bounding box.west);
                \draw (path picture bounding box.east) 
                    -- (path picture bounding box.west);    
            }
        }
    ]

        \node[multisquare={green/yellow}] (p1) at (0,1) {};
        \node[multisquare={green/yellow}] (p2) at (0,2) {};

        \draw[->] (p1) -- (p2);


        \foreach \i in {3,4} {
            \node[multisquare={red/blue}] (p\i) at (0,\i) {};
        }

        \draw[->] (p3) -- (p4);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Same output as above.

Comment: Is there a way to combine two squares as one object and use relative positioning? In the example shown above, can I directly use something similar to `\draw[->] (p3) -- (p4);` I tried to use local bouding box, but it does not work in my implementation. My plan is to define a new shape (it consists of two squares) and use it as one shape or define a new node consisting of two nodes and use it as one node.

Comment: @CNDominic You still want to have a node, because you want to end the edges at the border of the node. Therefore you cannot use a simple geometric drawing. But you can fill a node with a `path picture`. See the third example I added to my original answer. You can also take a look at [multi-part node shapes](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#pgf.rectangle:split), but these are not easily scalable in height (or width). Of course, you could also create your own custom node shape, but this is [not easy](https://tikz.dev/base-nodes#sec-106.5).

Comment: Thank you very much!